# Finding records between two dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet with a list of names in sheet 2 in each column of staff who will be in certain positions, Row 2 for each column has the week commencing date. On sheet 3 I have all staff members leave for certain periods. What I'd like to do is add the leave to the bottom of Sheet 2 if it falls within that week.

I've got the formula `=IF(AND(F1>=D2,D2<F1+6),"Yes","No")` which tells me if leave falls in the week, but I can't work out how to transpose the names over to the bottom of Sheet 2 starting in row 80.

Can anyone help?

-Cr1kk0

Comment: I've come up with the formula `=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$100,SMALL(IF(AND(F$1>=D9,D9<F$1+6,F$1<=E9)=TRUE,ROW($A$2:$A$100)-ROW($A$2)+1),ROWS(H$2:H9))),"")`, however it's putting the results in the same row, not after each other, and including row 2, even though it's not correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue was with the AND function, so used nested IF statements, the formula `=IFERROR(INDEX($G:$G,SMALL(IF(AJ$2>=$E:$E,IF($E:$E<AJ$2+6,IF(AJ$2<=$F:$F,ROW($G:$G)-ROW($G$1)+1))),ROWS(AJ$80:AJ80))),"")` is now working for me